# Brownian Motion (Geometric, Fractional, Drift)

Tags: terminology, definition, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have been researching Brownian motion for a while and have come across terms/types of Brownian motion such as fractional, geometric, and Brownian motion with drift. I understand the physical meaning of normal BM of particles suspended in a liquid and behaving chaotically but I don't understand the difference between these types or their physical meaning. I have read that geometric is used in finance but that is all I have understood so far.

Can someone explain these types without using too much mathematics if possible please? Specifically the 3 different types above but if there are any other more significant/common types then feel free to explain those briefly as well. Also if there are any good websites or videos clearly explaining these that would be much appreciated too.